# neo4j create the opposite edge

Tags: neo4j, cypher

i am new to neo4j and cypher , i need to create the opposite of all the edges of the graph but i need that the opposites edges to have the same type of the original edges
 
for illustration the opposite of `(a)-[:sometype]->(b)` would be `(b)-[:sometype]->(a)`
i know that it is very easy to create the opposite of all the edges by just tapping this command

`match (a)-[]->(b) create (b)-[]->(a)`

but as i have already said i need the created edge to have the same type of the original edge
thank you

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you need this? Neo4j can traverse relationships in either direction. If you DO actually need this, can you install [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) if you don't have it installed already? It has some dynamic relationship creation procedures that can help.

Comment: To underline one of @InverseFalcon's points: unless your use case has a *very good reason* to have the same relationship type going in both directions, you do not want to do that -- since the same relationship can be traversed just as easily in both directions, and it is a waste of DB storage and can make your queries slower and more complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this comment](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/45#issuecomment-272802777) in an open question in neo4j's Github this is not possible yet.

As said by InverseFalcon in this comment, you can use [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) to achieve this goal as described in [this post](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2016/10/30/neo4j-create-dynamic-relationship-type/) from Mark Needham blog.

Fist, install Apoc Procedures. After this, e.g.:

```
CREATE (a)-[:sometype]->(b)

//Match...
MATCH (a)-[r]->(b)
WITH r, a, b
// and use apoc.create.relationship to achieve your goal...
CALL apoc.create.relationship(b, TYPE(r), {}, a) YIELD rel
RETURN rel
```

Tested here:[image]