# Is it possible to merge using data-driven node or relationship labels?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm working with prepared statements via the Neo4J JDBC driver, and have a need to create node and relationship labels whose names are driven by the data we will be receiving.

For example, I'd like to create a prepared statement along these lines:

`MERGE (test:{1} {id: {2}) ON CREATE SET test.id = {2}`

OR

`MERGE (test:Test)-[:{1}]->(test2:Test)`

These don't currently work, as it seems Neo4J doesn't interpret the placeholder `{1}` as a placeholder, instead seeing it as an invalid label name.

Another possibility I'm exploring is that we may be able to extend Cypher via a stored procedure, though I suspect we may run into the same limitation.

Hoping someone can provide some insight as to whether there is any way to accomplish this with Cypher.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

An answer below suggests using APOC's `apoc.create.node` procedure, but what I need is to merge on a dynamic label. Updated the title to reflect this.

Comment: Hi! See [this related SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43594138/neo4j-create-the-opposite-edge).

Comment: Thanks @BrunoPeres - somehow couldn't find that during my searches!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using a different procedure from APOC - `apoc.cypher.doIt`, as it turns out APOC doesn't have a way to merge with dynamic labels as of yet. See feature request: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/issues/271

Below is what I ended up doing. Note that the requirement was to iterate (in this case using UNWIND) over a collection and merge nodes with dynamic labels pulled from this collection, and then merge a relationship between a pre-existing node and this new node:

```
WITH myNode, myList
UNWIND categories AS catArray
WITH myNode, 'MERGE (cat:' + catArray[0] + ' {value: "' + catArray[1] + '" }) ON CREATE SET cat.value = \"' + catArray[1] + '\" RETURN cat' AS cypher
CALL apoc.cypher.doIt(cypher, {}) YIELD value
WITH myNode, value.cat as cat
MERGE (myNode)-[:IN_CATEGORY]->(cat)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use APOC to create dynamic relationships. Similar APOC procedures exist for creating nodes with dynamic labels or adding dynamic labels to nodes.

```
MERGE (test:Test {name: 'Test'})
WITH test
MERGE (test2:Test {name: 'Test 2'})
WITH test, test2
CALL apoc.create.relationship(test, {new_rel_type}, {}, test2) YIELD rel
RETURN test, test2, rel
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks @dave-bennett - tried it in a sandbox and it seems to work after deploying the APOC plugin. Quick edit you may want to make to your answer: 

`YIELD new_rel` gave me an error: `Unknown procedure output: 'new_rel'` -  looks like it expects the output to be called `rel`.

Comment: Are you aware of a way to do this with `MERGE` instead of `CREATE`?  I've been looking over the APOC docs and it doesn't seem like it's supported currently.

Comment: Updated the question and removed this as accepted answer for now

Answer (score 0):

After trying almost half a day, I finally find out this method:

`UNWIND {batch} as row 
MERGE (n { id: row.id }) SET n += row.properties 
WITH n 
CALL apoc.create.addLabels(id(n), [n.label]) YIELD node
RETURN node`

and the performance is almost the same as purely MERGE.

Many thanks for this refer: [SET label : pass label name as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27189237/set-label-pass-label-name-as-parameter)